# NSString has null value when concatenated

Tags: uitableview, ios5, nsstring, abpeoplepickerview

I have a UITableView with multiple sections. A section of the tableview has 2 rows, of which one is editable(insert button) and other displays a name from addressbook.
On the click of the insert button in the cell, I am loading peoplePickerView and I select a contact.

I get the contact from addressbook as

```
- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController: (ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person {

    NSString *firstName = (__bridge NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);

    NSString *middleName = (__bridge NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonMiddleNameProperty);

    NSString *lastName = (__bridge NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty);

    self.contactName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@/%@", firstName ?: @"", middleName ?: @"", lastName ?: @""];

    [self.myTableView reloadData];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    return NO;
}
```

On tableview's cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{ 
    if(indexPath.section == 0){
        if(indexPath.row == 0){
        cell.textLabel.text = self.contactName;
        NSLog(@"Contact Name %@", self.contactName);
    }
    else{
        cell.textLabel.text = @"";
    }
}
}
```

When I set to the string, only the firstname property, then the string  has the right value, but when I try to concatenate the strings(first +middle+last names) and reload the tableview, I get a null value. What I am I doing wrong and how can I correct it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did wrong was declaring the property contactName as weak

```
@property(nonatomic, weak) NSString *contactName;
```

Also check for null before concatenating strings as Ahmad suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace the below line ..

```
self.contactName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@/%@", firstName ?: @"", middleName ?: @"", lastName ?: @""];
```

as like this and check..

```
self.contactName = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@/%@/%@", firstName ?: @"", middleName ?: @"", lastName ?: @""];
```

Comment: What I did wrong was declaring the property contactName as weak

`@property(nonatomic, weak) NSString *contactName;`

Comment: @XaviValero - that's fine, and try the above code also if needed.

Answer (score 0):

you have to make sure of two things

1. that you are initializing your self.contactName before calling `[NSString stringWithFormat...` for example in viewDidLoad do the following `self.contactName = [NSString alloc] init]`

2.if you try to concatenate a nil string to a string the final result would be also nil, make sure that all the strings contained in the concatenation code has values and not nil